# How to you store special characters such as "//$//" in redis as a value for a key using python?

Tags: python, caching, redis, backslash

I am trying to load data into redis cache from a csv file using python.
The data would be stored in a redis HSET. Here is how the data should be stored

In the data file the columns are as below

(key column)

city_name   | type | country | currency |

Newyork   | city | United States | Dollars /$/ |

Expected

```
Newyork:
{"type":"city", "country":"United States", "currency":"Dollars /$/"}
```

However on due to python's escape sequence the data load I am getting extra backslashes

Actual

```
Newyork:
{"type":"city", "country":"United States", "currency":"dollars ////$////"}
```

Comment: I think maybe you've put the wrong slashes into this question. Backslashes (\\) are used to escape characters in JSON, not (/ ).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways you can accomplish this depending on your need. The most 'native' way to do this is to json dump the dictionary into the hset key, this assumes you've done a **pip install redis**.

**Native hset**

```
import redis
import json
Newyork = {"type":"city", "country":"United States", "currency":"Dollars /$/"}
r = redis.Redis()
r.hset('something', 'yourfield', json.dumps(NewYork))
```

Looking in the redis-console we see:

```
redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> hget somehas afield2
"{\"type\": \"city\", \"country\": \"United States\", \"currency\": \"Dollars /$/\"}"
```

This also means you'll need to json.loads the result to access it later:

```
 import json
 import redis
 r = redis.Redis(decode_responses=True)
 xxx = json.loads('something', 'yourfield')
```

Alternatively, you could embrace redis json and build json documents.  Here's a complete example

**With redis json**

First, let's start a redis docker with redis-json support:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 --name redis-redisjson redislabs/rejson:latest
```

Now, let's use [redisjson](https://redisjson.io) to store our data. This assumes you've done a **pip install redisjson**.

```
from rejson import Client
cli = Client()
Newyork = {"type":"city", "country":"United States", "currency":"Dollars /$/"}
cli.jsonset('something', '.' Newyork)
```

This latter approach will store things with a JSON type, and a document rooted at '.'.

The advantage of this approach is the encoding and decoding is done for you by the redisjson client.

Comment: You got the point very correctly. Its the reloading the JSON which is causing this issue because I am doing it after dumping my JSON in a variable. Now I could not give the entire code due to copy rights but only the issue. But sincere thanks for sharing this solution to me. I guess I need to organize how I read my JSON data to fix this issue.

Comment: My pleasure @shivthedev! Mind closing this item / marking it as solved?